# Using PHP and want to get the Facebook access token in PHP (without SDK)

Tags: php, json, facebook

**My code as below :**

```
//Tie it all together to construct the URL
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=[ID]&client_secret=[key]&grant_type=client_credentials";

//Make the API call
$result = file_get_contents($url);

//Decode the JSON.
$decoded = json_decode($result, true);

//Dump it out.
var_dump($decoded);
var_dump($result);
```

I am not using PHP SDK (Facebook) and it doesn't work....
I run the same link in browser and it can return the access token in JSON.

Comment: Describe what actually happens and what results you got from your debug outputs - not just “doesn’t work”. And if you only want an app access token - you don’t need to make an API call for that, the combination of app id and app secret with a pipe symbol in between (`id|secret`) always works as an app access token.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you found the URL here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow

Don´t forget about the `code` parameter. You get it when the user authorizes your App. This is what you need: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#login